# CiviCRM Upgrade from 4.5beta6 to 4.6.8 - CiviCRM Menu is not displaying/functioning

Tags: upgrade, menu

Stepped upgrade from 4.5beta6 to 4.50 stable to 4.60 to 4.68. Was as beautiful and eventless an upgrade process as I've experienced. Congrats and thank you team.

My only QA issue is with the civicrm admin menu. It is busted.

I can confirm menujs script is loading. 
I can confirm html for the menu is present.
I can confirm there are no js errors.
I can confirm resource urls are fine. 
I have cleared the caches like a maniac.

So all I can think of is some crazy css conflict, but I can't even...

[image: a busy cat] 
[image: another kitty] 

Clicking on a link causes it to expand its LI's but incredibly broken-like.

Any ideas would be incredibly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To rule out a CSS conflict, try changing the CiviCRM admin theme to a "vanilla" theme, like Bartik.  If you have the "CiviCRM theme" module enabled (it ships with Civi), you can do this without affecting public-facing pages.
- You can also try a menu rebuild:
  `<yoursite.org>/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1`

Comment: This definitely helps. Using the bartik theme, the menu displays and functions appropriately, though little else does. This gives me something to go on. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing - I've seen the issue you're seeing here when my civicrm.css wasn't loading.  You may want to disable CSS aggregation and ensure that civicrm.css is loading.  Since you're not getting a 404 error, if civicrm.css isn't loading, it might be because you've selected "Disable civicrm.css" in the Resource URLs settings.

Answer (score 4):

Its a core issue, civicrm/css/navigation.css doesn't gets loaded if drupal already has navigation.css loaded.
Check if your custom theme has navigation.css included, this would cause the error for menu not getting displayed

Fix includes in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17234

HTH
Pradeep