# Civicrm menu is hidden

Tags: drupal

After upgrading civicrm to the latest version 4.6.8 for drupal6 site, my civicrm menu is hidden. Kindly help me to fix the issue I am new to civicrm.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew Hunt. Please use a flag rather than comment in future for possible duplicate of question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this steps :

1) Rebuild the menu by hitting this url `<your_site_name>/civicrm/menu/rebuild`

2) Clear Drupal cache using `drush cc all`

3) Clear browser cache -- mostly done with `Ctrl+Shift+Del`.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, thank you for your response. I tried your above steps but unfortunately rebuilding civicrm menu did not work.

Comment: may be you should have a look at solution provided in - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/civicrm-upgrade-from-4-5beta6-to-4-6-8-civicrm-menu-is-not-displaying-function