# After installation Civi menu and dashbord do not show (SOLVED)

Tags: wordpress, installation, dashboard, menu

after a successful installation of CiviCRM 4.7.19 on WordPress 4.7.4 – the installer said everything was fine –, the menu and dashboard of CiviCRM does not show.

I know, this issue has been addressed elsewhere, but the solutions proposed there didn't work for me.

For instance, in the following case: [Civi dashboard and menus won't display after install](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17483/civi-dashboard-and-menus-wont-display-after-install/17573#17573) the solution seemed to be to replace the CiviCRM Resource URL which was set to default. However, the solution does not say, how to find and access this Resource URLs settings page where this default would have to be changed.

In another solution [Word Press Install Missing civicrm.settings.php; dashboard unavailable; no menus](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/word-press-install-missing-civicrm-settings-php-dashboard-unavailable-no-menus) it was suggested to install a certain plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/ , which unfortunately also did not help me.

I've also looked into similar cases on Drupal, like this one: [Civicrm menu is hidden](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/civicrm-menu-is-hidden)
There someone suggested to rebuild the menu via adding /civicrm/menu/rebuild to my page, but it only gave me an error saying I'm not permitted to access that page.

I'd be glad to hear some of your ideas on this issue.

Thanks and best regards!
Jannis

EDIT: Posted the solution below.

Comment: Jannis, what does your civicrm.settings.php file show as the value for your BASEURL, is it correct, is your site using SSL (https)?  In 4.7 the civicrm settings file ends up in 'wp-content/uploads/civicrm' folder.

Comment: In the case where you cannot use the dashboard (and therefore Admin functions) to set 'resource URLs' you can go into the database to see what they're set to (and change them if needed): if you're using MySQL you can look at the civicrm_settings table and check 'value' where 'name' is like 'imageUploadURL' and 'userFrameworkResourceURL' (the latter should be your 'civicrm' root, like wp-content/plugins/civicrm..

Comment: double check your permissions?

Comment: Is there anything useful in the civicrm or webserver log files?

Comment: Dear all, thank a lot for your comments! @LesleyEvensen: I checked the BASEURL and it just said http://crm.netzwerk-n.org/, which is the right domain. But as petednz suggested that it might be a problem of permissions, I added "/wp-admin/" to the BASEURL, which however did not change anything.

Comment: I've also checked the civicrm_settings table, but it does not show 'imageUploadURL' and 'userFrameworkResourceURL', but for example 'wpBasePage', 'wpLoadPhp'. I've changed the values there according to my root (/usr/www/users/netzwefm/CRM/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/) to http://crm.netzwerk-n.org/CRM/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ and  http://crm.netzwerk-n.org/netzwefm/CRM/wp-load.php, respectively. But again, the dashboard did not show correctly and the menu did not show up at all.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: The permissions of which files exactly?

Comment: This might sound a stupid question but in the Wordpress/Admin/Plugins section, does it show that CiviCRM is actually activated?

Comment: @peterb: Thanks for your comment and to be honest, I'm rather a new to all this stuff, so every question (however stupid it may sound) is welcome ;) To answer your question: Yes it is activated. The CiviCRM-button also shows in the WordPress sidebar.

Comment: Check this section: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Comment: When you click on the Wordpress sidebar button "CiviCRM", what actually shows up? If it seems a blank page, is there any text in the footer including the words "System Status".  If there is, could you click on that and say what shows up?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: Thanks for clarifying! But those permissions I guess I should have automatically, since I'm logged with the account that installed wordpress and civicrm in the first place.

Comment: @peterb: A page shows up that says "CiviCRM Home Configure Your Dashboard Refresh Dashboard Data Welcome to your Home Dashboard Your […]" And in the footer it says "Access Keys: Powered by CiviCRM 4.7.19. System Status: Error […]" Directly after the installation it also said that Cron is not running, but I thought that shouldn't be a problem. When I click on "System Status: Error", a similar looking page loads, not saying what the error actually is about.

Comment: I've got the feeling, the problem might be that I had to install CiviCRM on a Wordpress system that's located not in the root, because there's another Wordpress located already. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Hey everyone! Thanks for all your good ideas. Finally I've solved it by going through the first case I've listed above: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17483/civi-dashboard-and-menus-wont-display-after-install/17573#17573 Though I could neither access the menu nor find the resource URL in my database, I found a link to the administer page in the case, which is wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin&reset=1 There I could change the default to the actual CiviCRM Resource URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all your good ideas. Finally I've solved it by going through the first case I've listed above: [Civi dashboard and menus won't display after install](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17483/).

Though I could neither access the menu nor find the resource URL in my database, I found a link to the administer page in the case, which is `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin&reset=1` There I could change the default to the actual CiviCRM Resource URL.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question!  I see you've marked the question as "SOLVED" in the title.  Could you please check the box next to this answer to indicate that this is the correct answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this page, with a similar issue.

In my case it was because I was configuring a Staging Server clone of the live site.  I had not yet added an exemption for the new site to my NoScript browser extension, so JavaScript was not running.  Oops.  Maybe this will help someone else.